# I want to disable JEDI string property editor

Tags: delphi, jedi

How can I disable JEDI string property editor?

I have tried to disable these lines

```
  // RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TCaption), TJvHTLabel, 'Caption', TJvHintProperty);
```

in jvcl\design\jvCtrlsReg.pas then I have used the JEDI installer to do a full reinstall (with "rebuild packages" option active).

No success.

Comment: I think that should do it (assuming these properties are the ones you want). Check paths, duplicate packages, and verify that the package you're recompiling is the one installed in IDE

Comment: These seems to be the editors that I need to remove. However, the editor is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open JvCoreDxxD.dpk in the IDE.

Ctrl+Enter on JvCoreReg.pas

Comment the below two lines in JvCoreReg.pas

```
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(string), BaseClass, 'Hint', TJvHintProperty);
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TCaption), BaseClass, '', TJvHintProperty);
```

Install the package.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these are the properties you are trying to change, I would first remove the package from delphi (which should delete all components from the pallates) then recompile and reinstall.